# How to use BLE Shield based on HM-10 bluetooth module?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I'm a new bie on arduino projects. I would like to ask you for some help. I bought a BLE Shield for Arduino from ( http://imall.iteadstudio.com/development-platform/arduino/shields/im130704001.html ). They made this shield using Hm-10 Bluetooth module(http://www.jnhuamao.cn/bluetooth.asp?ID=1). Itead Studio has no sample codes using this shield. I have no idea on how to program it or send AT commands from Arduino.

I read the “AT commands” at the data sheet (ftp://imall.iteadstudio.com/Shield/IM130704001_ITEAD_BLE_Shield/DS_IM130704001_ITEAD_BLE_Shield.pdf) and I tried to send "AT commands” from arduino to BLE shield using this code ( http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial ) but I only received the commands back.

Did anybody here ever use this HM-10 bluetooth module ?

I need some arduino sketch for help !

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

  int led         = 13;
  int bluetoothTx = 2;
  int bluetoothRx = 3;
  SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx); 
  int baudrate[8] ={4800,9600,14400,19200,28800,38400,57600,115200};
  int i = 1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial){}

  Serial.write("AT sent");
  delay(500);
  bluetooth.write("AT+NAME?");
  delay(500);
  while (bluetooth.available()) {
     Serial.write(bluetooth.read());
   }
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("");

  bluetooth.write("AT+POWE3");
  delay(500);
  while(bluetooth.available()) 
  {
    Serial.write(bluetooth.read());
  }
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("");

  delay(500);
  bluetooth.write("AT+CHAR?");
  delay(500);
  while (bluetooth.available()) {
     Serial.write(bluetooth.read());
   }
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("");

  delay(500);
  bluetooth.write("AT+NAMEFlightline"); //Check Status
  delay(500);
  while (bluetooth.available()) {
      Serial.write((char)bluetooth.read());

    }

  Serial.println("");
  bluetooth.write("AT+CHAR0x2901"); //add charicteristic
  delay(500);
  while (bluetooth.available()) {
      Serial.write(bluetooth.read());

    }
  Serial.println("");
  bluetooth.write("AT+RELI0"); 
  delay(500);
  while (bluetooth.available()) {
      Serial.write(bluetooth.read());
    }
  Serial.println("");
  bluetooth.write("AT+SHOW1");
  delay(100);
  while (bluetooth.available()) {
      Serial.write(bluetooth.read());

    }
  Serial.println("");

  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
}

void testAllBaudRates(){
  for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
   {
      bluetooth.begin(baudrate[j]);
      delay(100);
      Serial.println("boud rate " + String(baudrate[j],DEC) +" i-> "+String(j,DEC));
     // Serial.println("");
      bluetooth.write("AT");
      delay(500);
      while (bluetooth.available()) {
        Serial.write(bluetooth.read());
        Serial.println();
       }
       delay(100);
   }
}                                            

// and now a few blinks of the  LED, 
// so that we know the program is running

void loop()
{
  //Read from bluetooth and write to usb serial
  while(bluetooth.available())
  {
    char toSend = (char)bluetooth.read();
    if(toSend == 'x'){
       digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
       Serial.println("set high");
       bluetooth.write("RXOK");
    }else if(toSend == 'y'){
      digitalWrite(led,LOW);
      Serial.println("set low");
      bluetooth.write("RXOK");
    }
    Serial.print(toSend);

  }

  //Read from usb serial to bluetooth
  while(Serial.available())
  {
    char toSend = (char)Serial.read();
    bluetooth.write(toSend);
    Serial.print(toSend);
  }
}
```

Have a look at my sketch above I have a few things to point out that I wasted time on.

make sure you have the line

```
while(!Serial){}
```

Or you may get have a working shield but miss the responses as the serial monitor is no ready.

remember that you wont get a response from the blue-tooth module, with a command from the Serial Monitor if it is connected to a device. It is connected to the device when the light stops flashing.

if you run this sketch you should get this output

```
AT sent
OK+Set:3
OK+Get:0x2901  <- this may be blank the first time you run it
OK+Set:Flightline
OK+Set:0x2901
OK+Set:0
OK+Set:1
```

the most comprehensive list of AT commands can be found here

```
[All the AT commands and a good explanation][1]
```

You will need to at Characteristics to the device as I have done here

```
bluetooth.write("AT+CHAR?");
```

or you will find it to connect to iOS and Android

If you are connecting to Android use the BluetoothLE Classes not Bluetooth ones.

Comment: You wrote a very super and quick code for humanity. Thanks a lot. I did it well! Loves.

Comment: How can we make a new Bluetooth service without connect option? on Arduino?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean sorry

Comment: When you run your code, you need to click on "connect" button to read/write hex data. I ask, as showing UUID of your BLE, is it possible that sending datas seems like no need to connect like temperature value on Arduino?

Comment: write another question and I can post that code for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this sketch](https://github.com/4ntoine/mega-to-hm10) with baud rate autodetect to control your HM-10. This is a part of [Apploader project](http://www.apploader.info/) that allows to upload to Arduino board over BLE.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late too, but try the following code, if you send it "AT" it should give you back an "OK":

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>  

int bluetoothTx = 2;  // TX-O pin of bluetooth mate, Arduino D2
int bluetoothRx = 3;  // RX-I pin of bluetooth mate, Arduino D3

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  // Begin the serial monitor at 9600bps

  bluetooth.begin(115200);  // The Bluetooth Mate defaults to 115200bps
  delay(100);  // Short delay, wait for the Mate to send back CMD
  bluetooth.println("U,9600,N");  // Temporarily Change the baudrate to 9600, no parity
  // 115200 can be too fast at times for NewSoftSerial to relay the data reliably
  bluetooth.begin(9600);  // Start bluetooth serial at 9600
}

void loop()
{
  if(bluetooth.available())  // If the bluetooth sent any characters
  {
    // Send any characters the bluetooth prints to the serial monitor
    Serial.print((char)bluetooth.read());  
  }
  if(Serial.available())  // If stuff was typed in the serial monitor
  {
    // Send any characters the Serial monitor prints to the bluetooth
    bluetooth.print((char)Serial.read());
  }
  // and loop forever and ever!
}
```

Comment: ITS NOT WORKING,  why anyway you do : bluetooth.begin(115200); ?? the hm-10 baud is 9600 ,i dont get this line, the default is not 115200 , they never say that . also , if you just connect things to the uno and try to connect nothing is happens