# Cant connect the HM-10 bluetooth to Arduino Uno

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, arduino-uno, hm-10

I have tried everything, really, everything.
The `HM-10` module(bluetooth), has its led and its blinks, than if you connect to it from their app, the led stop blinking and you get the `UUID` on the iDevice.

Problem starts when you try to program the module from its `UART` and send `"AT"` to get `"OK"` , from the arduino serial monitor(on mac ) .

So, i was trying to connect its `tx/rx` via ttl converter to the arduino uno and send commands from the monitor, didn't work.

than i was trying to connect it directly and used this link :
[How to use BLE Shield based on HM-10 bluetooth module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826749/how-to-use-ble-shield-based-on-hm-10-bluetooth-module)

didn't work(no respond for "AT" ) .

I have also tried this :
http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Bluetooth_V4.0_HM-11_BLE_Module

and this:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-RGB-lights-from-Android-with-Arduino-Bluet/step1/Assemble-test-configure-your-Bluetooth-LE-module/

With no respond .i dont get any respond from the module (module rx goes to tx on arduino )

I dont really know whats the deal with this module, maybe its broken ( if so, how can i connect to it from my iPad and get its UUID ?? ) .

Is there anything else i can do ?? is there an option that i have put it in some mode that it can't respond anymore ?

Comment: Normally you would not connect the module to the arduino rx/tx pins, as those are already used to connect to the PC, but instead to arbitrary digitalpins and use a software serial. An exception would be a leonardo type board.  Another would be to remove the atmega328p and use the arduino board only as a usb converter, but then you connect rx-rx and tx-tx.  Of course wrong baud rate or misinterpreted pinout are always a concern, too.

Comment: did you found any solution? Same problem.

Answer (score 5):

I discovered my device is : BLE-CC41-A, a HM-10 rip off

The commands overlap a bit, but are different, a good command to help you out is:

AT+HELP/CR/LF

Doc for the BLE-CC41-A: 
http://img.banggood.com/file/products/20150104013200BLE-CC41-A_AT%20Command.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There is an app for iOS that makes using the HM-10 easy to use. It is for a single pin output. There is also a link the sketch for it. I used it with Arduino Nano, HM-10, a Relay, junction box, and an outlet to turn my room light off at night without getting out of my bed. The app is FatBeard HM10 here https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fatbeard-hm10/id1198432512?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

The Baud rates / parameters correspondences are not the same with BLE-CC41-A or true HM-10, it's well mentioned in the Doc for the BLE-CC41-A referred in the second answer. There are some other differences.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't know exactly what is your BT (HM-10 or CC41-A)
maybe you can try this one..

https://rydepier.wordpress.com/2015/10/22/comparing-the-hm10-and-ble-cc41a-bluetooth/

I bought one HM-10 but what i got is CC41-A
I turn my BT as a master, and don't forget to use NEWLINE or BOTH NR & CL neither NO LINE ENDING

Answer (score 0):

In the Arduino serial monitor, did you remember to turn off the "Carriage Return" option?  The HM-1X expects "AT" not, "AT\r"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set the same baud rate in both Arduino sketch (`Serial.begin(115200)`) and in HM-10 module settings(`AT+BAUD4`). You can use https://github.com/4ntoine/mega-to-hm10 example. A part of Apploader app that allow to upload arduino sketches from iOS devices to Arduino: http://www.apploader.info

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm playing myself with an fake HM-10 (CC41-A) since a few days. I figured out that the baud in the datasheet didn't fit.
So I recompiled my Arduino sketch several times to test all BAUD rates and finally I found a rate where it startet answering to AT-commands, again.

I's suggest you should do the same. Check all baud rates on your CC41-A connection until you get en OK to an AT.

Mine required 'Both NL & CR' on the Arduino SerialMonitors settings if I enter commands manuall, as well as an `<mySerial>.println("AT");` instead of `<mySerial>.print("AT");`!